# Dash Plotly - How to redirect to external link which will redirect to Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, fitbit

I'm working with Fitbit's api and Dash Plotly.

I'm trying to get Fitbit's `access_token`, which you can get by accessing this URL:

```
"https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={FITBIT_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8050%2F&scope=activity%20heartrate%20location%20nutrition%20profile%20settings%20sleep%20social%20weight&expires_in=604800"
```

This URL will redirect to the http://127.0.0.1:8050/ with a code at the end of the URL http://127.0.0.1:8050/#access_token=.....

I'm trying to get that `access_token` with Dash.

**The problem:**

- Redirect works and provides the access token, but ends in an endless loop using `dcc.Location(id="auth_url", refresh=True href=authorization_url,)`
- Using callbacks to switch the `refresh` attribute inside `dcc.Location` to False don't seem to work.
- Using `if "access_token=" in pathname:` doesn't seem to catch the pathname in the address bar `print (pathname)` prints `"/"` despite the address bar having the URL including the code

code:

```
def auth():
return html.Div(
        dcc.Location(id="auth_url", href=authorization_url, refresh=True)
        )


@app.callback(
    Output("auth_url", "refresh"),
    Input("auth_url", "pathname")
)
def callback(pathname):
    print (pathname)
    if "access_token" in pathname:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if there is a standard method to redirect to external links through the Dash API without user input. However, I was able to do this by creating a new Flask endpoint that redirects and defining that endpoint in dcc.Location.

```py
@app.server.route("/redirect/")
def redirect():
    '''
    This function redirects to the SSO authorization url
    by utilizing the Flask API directly instead of the 
    Dash API.
    '''
    return flask.redirect(authorization_url)

def auth():
    return html.Div(
        dcc.Location(id="auth_url", href='/redirect/', refresh=True)
    )

@app.callback(
    Output("auth_url", "refresh"),
    Input("auth_url", "pathname")
)
def callback(pathname):
    print (pathname)
    if "access_token" in pathname:
        return False
```